# BreadCrumb including menu item

Tags: php, wordpress

I have integrated a html template to wordpress theme. But, Not getting the proper breadcrumb.

Below is ORIGINAL BREADCRUMB......

[image]

I`m getting BREADCRUMB is like below.....

[image]

My breadCrumb function is like below....in functions.php

```
    function my_breadcrumb()
{
    if(!is_front_page())
    {
        echo '<a href="';echo get_option('home');echo '">'; echo "Home"; echo "</a>";
        echo "&nbsp;";
        echo "<span class='skt-breadcrumbs-separator'> / </span>";
        echo "&nbsp;";
    }
    if(is_category() || is_single())
    {
        $category = get_the_category();
        $ID = $category[0]->cat_ID;
        echo get_category_parents($ID, TRUE, ' &#47; ', FALSE );
    }
    if(is_single() || is_page())
    {
        echo "<span>"; the_title(); echo "</span>";
    }
    if(is_tag())
    {
        single_tag_title('',FALSE);
    }
    if(is_404())
    {
        echo "404 - Page not Found";
    }
    if(is_search())
    {
        echo "Search";
    }
    if(is_year())
    {
        echo get_the_time('Y');
    }
    echo "";
}
```

The NEWS menu-item is sub menu of COMPANY menu-item...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2269/wordpress-built-in-breadcrumb-trail-menu

Comment: Not really that I want. I want to do this without any plugin. @bodi0

Comment: Is 'News' a subpage of Company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function the_breadcrumb() {
    global $post;
    echo '<ul id="breadcrumbs">';
    if (!is_home()) {
        echo '<li><a href="';
        echo get_option('home');
        echo '">';
        echo 'Home';
        echo '</a></li><li class="separator"> / </li>';
        if (is_category() || is_single()) {
            echo '<li>';
            the_category(' </li><li class="separator"> / </li><li> ');
            if (is_single()) {
                echo '</li><li class="separator"> / </li><li>';
                the_title();
                echo '</li>';
            }
        } elseif (is_page()) {
            if($post->post_parent){
                $anc = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
                $title = get_the_title();
                foreach ( $anc as $ancestor ) {
                    $output = '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($ancestor).'" title="'.get_the_title($ancestor).'">'.get_the_title($ancestor).'</a></li> <li class="separator">/</li>';
                }
                echo $output;
                echo '<strong title="'.$title.'"> '.$title.'</strong>';
            } else {
                echo '<li><strong> '.get_the_title().'</strong></li>';
            }
        }
    }
    elseif (is_tag()) {single_tag_title();}
    elseif (is_day()) {echo"<li>Archive for "; the_time('F jS, Y'); echo'</li>';}
    elseif (is_month()) {echo"<li>Archive for "; the_time('F, Y'); echo'</li>';}
    elseif (is_year()) {echo"<li>Archive for "; the_time('Y'); echo'</li>';}
    elseif (is_author()) {echo"<li>Author Archive"; echo'</li>';}
    elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) {echo "<li>Blog Archives"; echo'</li>';}
    elseif (is_search()) {echo"<li>Search Results"; echo'</li>';}
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Your function was not looking for child pages.